# Cannot install cross-env on Laravel 5.5 fresh project

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, homestead

I'm trying to install corss-env on fresh Laravel 5.5 project.

I'm using

```
node v6.12.0
nmp 3.10.10
Vagrant 2.0.1
laravel/homestead (virtualbox, 4.0.0) on Windows 10
Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
```

I have been searching on the web, I'll try the following suggestions, but neither have solved the issue

- https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/478
- https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/issues/493
- https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/805
- https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-mix-windows-npm-error?page=1

This is the console output

```
$ npm install --save-dev cross-env 
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents): 
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"}) 
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-92-generic 
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "cross-env" 
npm ERR! node v6.12.0 
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10 
npm ERR! path ../cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js     
npm ERR! code EPROTO 
npm ERR! errno -71 
npm ERR! syscall symlink

npm ERR! EPROTO: protocol error, symlink '../cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js' -> '/home/vagrant/code/laravel-5.5/node_modules/.bin/cross-env' 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at: 
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request: 
npm ERR!     /home/vagrant/code/laravel-5.5/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: What does the npm-debug.log say?

Comment: See it here: https://pastebin.com/vj3gDbsk